# How costly are the Python dict and set in-built types?

Tags: python, data-structures, complexity, hashing

I have undertaken a [project](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107735/how-do-i-go-about-data-deduplication-at-scale) concerning database deduplication. I did some research and have found that the Python dict type actually is a hashmap that uses [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing).

In the deduplication module, we'll have some rules that determine whether two records are identical, with the rules essentially spelling out the attributes that uniquely identify the record (did not call it a candidate key as the DB is going to be non-relational, no-sql). Now let's say we deal with a really large dataset. Naturally, hashing is the way to go ( found that advice [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107735/how-do-i-go-about-data-deduplication-at-scale)).

The question(s):

- does the module need to compute a hash *and* then store it in a dict? Would that not be unnecessary, as the dict implementation is itself a hashmap?
- how costly is the conversion of a list to a set? That conversion should remove all the duplicates, but given the huge scale, is that practical?
- what is the cost incurred in checking membership in a dict/set using the "in" keyword?

Hadoop MapReduce is not an option at least for now.

I can't really dive into the Python sources to figure this out, as I'm strictly time limited :|

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "conversion of a dict to a set"? A dict is a mapping from unique keys to values, and a set is a collection of unique values. So, what do you want to be in the set?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I meant converting a list to a set :)

Comment: The dict implementation is a hashmap, true, but is the hash function suitable for what you're doing?  For deduplication, you probably want hash functions with large outputs that almost never collide, which is probably not ideal for a general-purpose in-memory hash.

Comment: @DavidThornley yes, but I thought the collisions are taken care of internally using open addressing/closed hashing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

That should pretty much cover everything.  What more do you need that's not already on this page?

Comment: searching a dict using in? let me guess: O(1) average and O(n) worst?

Comment: @yatisagade: `in` is effectively `try: __getitem__(key); return True; except KeyError: return False`.  So (generally) `in` generally behaves like `__getitem__`.

Comment: How about space complexity?